# MySQL query for club name with multiple player IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: table club]

I want to select club_name which is having multiple player_id. Like yeshwant is having two club_ids 1,2 I just need to select yeshwant. I tried using this query but was unable to do it

```
select club_name,count(club_name) as t from club  where count(club_name) >1 group by club_name;
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Hi @PuneetYadav Your query is very close for getting correct result. Remove WHERE clause and same condition is used at HAVING clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this.

```
SELECT T_Clubs.club_name, Count(T_Clubs.club_name) AS CountOfclub_name
FROM T_Clubs
GROUP BY T_Clubs.club_name
HAVING (((Count(T_Clubs.club_name))>1));
```

I noticed it was difficult to identify what objects you are working with. I like to use a naming convention for tables, queries, forms, etc... where each table begins with T_{table_name}; queries begin with Q_{query_name} etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
select club_name,count(club_name) as t 
  from club
group by club_name
having count(club_name)>1;
```

Filtering by aggregates should be done after group by and using the having clause.

Answer (score 0):

To find the club_names that have more than one player you just need a simple aggregate:

```
select club_name
from club
group by club_name
having count(*)>1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
select *
from
    (
       select club_name,count(club_name) as t 
       from club  
       group by club_name;
    ) t1
where t > 1
```